# php mysql insert statement

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to put a bit of dummy data directly into a table I have created:

```
$sql = "CREATE TABLE customers
(
customer_id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
customer_joindate DATE NOT NULL,
customer_title varchar(8) NOT NULL,
customer_firstname varchar(20) NOT NULL,
customer_surname varchar(20) NOT NULL,
customer_dob DATE,
customer_email varchar(60),
customer_phone varchar(14),
customer_lastupdate TIMESTAMP,
PRIMARY KEY (customer_id)
)TYPE = INNODB;";
```

I would like the join date to be the current date and I believe the timestamp will handle itself? So I tried the following insert:

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO customers (customer_joindate, customer_title, customer_firstname, customer_surname, customer_dob, customer_email, customer_phone)
VALUES (CURDATE(), 'Mr', 'John', 'Smith', '1985-11-01', 'john.smith@gmail.com', ''+4477665434')");
```

That doesn't seem to be inserting anything, could someone please tell me where I have gone wrong?

Comment: Are you getting an error message? If so please include it. If not, you should append `or die(mysql_error())` to your query statement.

Comment: I see an extra `'` here  `''+4477665434')");`  `mysql_error()` would reveal the location of the problem...

Comment: Michael is right. It works if you correct it: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/db33b/4

Comment: Thanks, I actually had another error too which @JYelton helped me find, appreciate the help everyone.

Comment: @mao consider posting an answer with brief details so this question can appear as completed.

Answer (score 1):

Try using 'ENGINE' instead of 'TYPE' :

```
CREATE TABLE 'customers'
(
'customer_id' int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
'customer_joindate' DATE NOT NULL,
'customer_title' varchar(8) NOT NULL,
'customer_firstname' varchar(20) NOT NULL,
'customer_surname' varchar(20) NOT NULL,
'customer_dob' DATE,
'customer_email' varchar(60),
'customer_phone' varchar(14),
'customer_lastupdate' TIMESTAMP,
PRIMARY KEY ('customer_id')
) ENGINE=INNODB;
```

For more information check the [MySql Manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-table.html).

As far as I know 'TYPE' is deprecated for newer versions of MySql.

Answer (score 0):

as suggested I used die(mysql_error()) to find the problems:

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO customers (customer_joindate, customer_title, customer_firstname, customer_surname, customer_dob, customer_email, customer_phone)
VALUES (CURDATE(), 'Mr', 'John', 'Smith', '1985-11-01', 'john.smith@gmail.com', '+447766543498')")or die(mysql_error());  ;
```